# SQL Server : select from a table containing &

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, ampersand

I'm unable to select from a table that contains & (ampersand). I'm querying the SQL Server database using VB.NET, the exception it throws is

> *incorrect syntax near '&'*

Here's the code I'm using:

```
Using Com As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Appointments&Results", Conn)
Using RDR = Com.ExecuteReader()
    If RDR.HasRows Then
        Do While RDR.Read
        'Get values here
        Loop
    End If
End Using
End Using
```

And here are queries that I've tried:

```
SELECT * FROM `Appointments&Results`
SELECT * FROM 'Appointments&Results'
SELECT * FROM `Appointments&&Results`
SELECT * FROM `Appointments&amp;Results`
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM [Appointments&Results]
```

That answers your question.

**My** question is, who in the world named the table with an ampersand (`&`)?!

Comment: Thanks! I agree completely, you wouldn't believe how messy this database is. Being halted by an ampersand was just the icing... thanks again! (waiting 5mins so I can accept)